# $request->file("file") is null after being passed to API

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4

I am currently having an issue with a file upload (it's for multiple files but I can't get one file to upload yet). After I've submitted the form with a file and dumped out the request data the front-end controller shows the data as I would expect.

```
    array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "SOME RANDOM TOKEN"
  "file" => array:1 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#633 ▼
      -test: false
      -originalName: "example.pdf"
      -mimeType: "application/pdf"
      -size: 194007
      -error: 0
      #hashName: null
      path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\tmp"
      filename: "phpA9B4.tmp"
      basename: "phpA9B4.tmp"
      pathname: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\tmp\phpA9B4.tmp"
      extension: "tmp"
      realPath: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\tmp\phpA9B4.tmp"
      aTime: 2018-03-08 16:13:17
      mTime: 2018-03-08 16:13:17
      cTime: 2018-03-08 16:13:17
      inode: 0
      size: 194007
      perms: 0100666
      owner: 0
      group: 0
      type: "file"
      writable: true
      readable: true
      executable: false
      file: true
      dir: false
      link: false
      linkTarget: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\tmp\phpA9B4.tmp"
    }
  ]
]
```

I then pass the data to my API
using this code and directly return the response back (this is just for testing purposes).

```
 $api = new Api();
 $code = $api->request('POST', $api->url('/attachment/document-upload'), $request->all());
 return Response::create($api->response['response'], $code);
```

**The API works for every other post but this one**

but when I dump out the file in the back end using `$request->file("file");` 
It always returns null.

I am a bit of a loss as I've never posted files to an API and I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

**The issue is regarding the API recieveing the files and the enctype in the front end form is set to multipart/form-data**

**edit - added the back-end controller function**

```
public function document_upload(Request $request)
{

    $files = $request->file("file");
    return  response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $request->header()]);
}
```

**request headers**

```
    {#631 ▼
  +"status": "error"
  +"message": {#633 ▼
    +"content-type": array:1 [▼
      0 => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
    +"content-length": array:1 [▼
      0 => "181"
    ]
    +"user-agent": array:1 [▼
      0 => "some ssl"
    ]
    +"host": array:1 [▼
      0 => "some server"
    ]
    +"authorization": array:1 [▼
      0 => "Bearer 
     some token
    ]
    +"accept-encoding": array:1 [▼
      0 => "deflate, gzip"
    ]
    +"accept": array:1 [▼
      0 => "*/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've had to change some stuff being passed but that's the general gist of it.

Comment: add the way you are making the request (with headers), the code of your controller and the code of your test.

Comment: @HCK I've added all that I can, I've had to change some details though.

Comment: why do you expect that to work ?  APIs are not for unloading files, if you check middlewares for api group in Laravel, you will get what I say

Comment: could you print this `$request->file->path()` and check the output ?